# [Video Sequence Editor]Blender only using 6% of cpu max appears to be performing the work in a single threaded manner

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

I am trying to render a raw screen capture video using blender and the rendering process is extremely slow.  It is taking about 4hrs+ to render 35mins of footage.  I see that blender is only utilizing 6%(at most) of my cpu when rendering, why is this?  I've tried looking into the issue and came back with trying to manually set my threads and fiddle around with tile size but I see no change in performance with these solutions.  It seems like its doing all the work in one thread as well even though on both auto and fixed it is set to 16 threads.

I have a Ryzen 7 1700 processer and a GTX 1080 graphics card.

I am very new to this so any guidance would be appreciated.  Below I've included a screenshot showing how low my utilization is while rendering a video in blender.

[image]

Comment: Blender's video editing capabilities are quite primitive and antiquated. With your hardware you should get GPU accelelerated playback in real time using Davinci Resolve. Use free version and keep blender to generate 3D content.

Comment: Thanks for the response I'll try that out now and see if that performs better for me

Comment: I've tried it out and davinci is much faster.  For now since my captures need no editing I am using ffmpeg directly. Below are some resources others may find helpful.
https://www.tal.org/tutorials/ffmpeg_nvidia_encode
https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg